# Gradle task doLast if task fails

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

I want a clean build, where you can see exactly what happened, but all information is preserved - so essentially for every task, I want it to write the output to a file, and only display it *if the task fails*.

I've tried to achieve this in gradle - but am being defeated because doLast doesn't run if the task fails.  Here's my "almost" working pattern:

```
task fakeTask( type: Exec ) {

    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'silly'
    doLast {
        new File("build.log") << standardOutput.toString()
        if (execResult.exitValue != 0) println standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

is there any alternative to doLast that will run any time?  Any other way of doing this? - especially as I want to do this for every single task I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `ignoreExitValue true` to your task definition to suppress throwing of an exception when the exit value is non-zero.

Comment: I did wonder about that - but essentially I _don't_ want to ignore the exit value - can I then make the task fail once I do what I need?

Comment: actually, this isn't that bad:task fakeTask( type: Exec ) {
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'silly'
    ignoreExitValue = true;
    doLast {
        new File("fakeTaskOutput.txt") << standardOutput.toString()
        if (execResult.exitValue != 0) 
        {
            println standardOutput.toString()
            throw new GradleException("faketask returned exitcode of " + execResult.exitValue )
        }
    }
}

Comment: Exactly, you tell the exec task to ignore exit value, but you handle it yourself and throw an exception at the end.

Answer (score 7):

this is my final solution:

```
tasks.withType( Exec ) {
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ignoreExitValue = true
    doLast {
        new File("gradle.log") << standardOutput.toString()
        if (execResult.exitValue != 0) 
        {
            println standardOutput.toString()
            throw new GradleException(commandLine.join(" ") + " returned exitcode of " + execResult.exitValue )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the task graph as documented at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:task_execution to execute code after a task has run.

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { task, state ->
    if (task instanceof ExecTask && state.failure) {
        file('gradle.log') << standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: As of right now, method 'afterTask' is deprecated, because is doesn't support configuration cache: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#afterTask-groovy.lang.Closure-